# Stencil.js: component level server side rendering

Tags: javascript, server-side-rendering, stenciljs, graaljs

The [stencil docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/hydrate-app) propose a way for server side rendering that works on a page level. It creates one whole of a hydrate app, which holds all the components created in a single index.js file which consumes whole of a HTML source page as input.

Is there a way to do server side rendering of web components component by component? The basic idea that I need to carry is by doing SSR via graaljs on a java backend. The above is taking a phenomenal time to load, a whopping 30s in an initial paint and 8-9sec on further loads. The input page can be as complex as 150kB.